# DropDownList with ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, actionlink

I'm trying to replicate the answer found below:
[is it posible do have Html.ActionLink inside a DropDownList Without java script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088042/is-it-posible-do-have-html-actionlink-inside-a-dropdownlist-without-java-script)

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "url",
    new SelectList(new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Home", Value = Url.Action("Home", "Home") },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "About", Value = Url.Action("About", "Home") },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Contact", Value = Url.Action("Contact", "Home") },
    }, "Value", "Text"),
    "Change View",
    new { id = "urlddl" }
)

$(function() {
    $('#urlddl').change(function() {

        var url = $(this).val();
        if (url != null && url != '') {
            window.location.href = url;
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is, when i select an item in the DropDownList, nothing happened. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: I've edit it to what it was suppose to be. I edit the code and paste the wrong one.

Comment: `var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();`

Comment: But what is the point? And your `if/else` block makes no sense - you already have the url by using `$(this).val()`  - just follow the code in the link you included in the question and use `location.href` to redirect

Comment: Your current code generates invalid script! (check view source of the rendered page). All you need is this one line in the change event handler `location.href=$(this).val();`

Comment: Sorry that was typo. I changed it afterward and paste the wrong code it was originally :     window.location.href = url;

Comment: @Shyju I've tried location.href instead of window.location.href and same problem

Comment: Use `$(this).val()` which will give you the value attribute value of the selected option (which has the url )

Comment: Thanks maybe i had a type somewhere earlier so it didnt work. it's working now