# How to view dropdown list in Navigation bar in shared page using database data in asp .net mvc

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to view dropdown in the shared page

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.DropDownListFor()</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

this above file name is `_Layout.cshtml`.
I have a table in my database named `headings`. in this table column as `helps`.
I want to add a button "Helps" along with "Home", "Contact", and "About". Such that when we click on "Helps" it shows a dropdown with all the values stored in the table headings in "helps" column.
How should I do it.

Comment: this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088042/is-it-posible-do-have-html-actionlink-inside-a-dropdownlist-without-java-script) had the same problem with you. you can see their answer

Comment: this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088042/is-it-posible-do-have-html-actionlink-inside-a-dropdownlist-without-java-script) had the same problem with you. you can see their answer

Comment: nicely illustrated [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2142681.aspx?How+to+populate+a+dropdownlist+on+Layout+Page)