# I need to replace ActionLink for Dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a `foreach` that it gives me a list of values that when click it call a controller:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>@Html.ActionLink(item.Text, "UpdateController",
                new { subSectionID = item.Value, subsectionName = item.Text })</div>
}
```

I would like to do this but now using a dropdown list where clicking on the value redirects me to the controller.

If someone knows how to do it or do it in some other way, maybe using Select in html, it would help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  
    $('#subsec').change(function () {
        
        var url = $(this).val();               

        if (url != null && url != '') { 
            window.location.href = url;
        }
    });
</script>

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.GetEnumerator().Current,
    Model.Select(d =>
    {
        return new SelectListItem() {
            Text = d.Text,
            Value = Url.Action("Your_Action_Name", "Your_Controller_Name",  new { subSectionID = d.Value, subsectionName = d.Text })

        };
    }),
    "-Select a value-",
    new { id = "subsec" })
```

A similar solution you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6088047/6630084